# Запись бинарных данных в реестр

Tags: delphi, реестр

Пытаюсь изменить значение реестра типа `reg_binary`

```
type
  TBuffer = array[0..11] of byte;
   const InputData:TBuffer=($07,$00,$00,$00,$6F,$2B,$15,$00,$40,$AB,$D3,$01);
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
  InputBuffer: TBuffer;
begin
InputBuffer := InputData;

  Reg := TRegistry.Create();
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if Reg.OpenKey('....', True) then
    begin
      Reg.WriteBinaryData('Health',InputBuffer, SizeOf(InputBuffer));//пробовал и InputBuffer[0]
      Reg.CloseKey;
    end;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
```

Пробовал и так :

```
var
   Data: array of Byte;

....

SetLength(Data, 12);
  Data[0] := $07;
  Data[1] := $00;
  Data[2] := $00;
  Data[3] := $00;
  Data[4] := $6F;
  Data[5] := $2B;
  Data[6] := $15;
  Data[7] := $00;
  Data[8] := $40;
  Data[9] := $AB;
  Data[10] := $D3;
  Data[11] := $01;

  Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_SET_VALUE);
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if Reg.OpenKey('....', True) then
    begin
      Reg.WriteBinaryData('Health',Data, 12); //пробовал и Data[0]
      Reg.CloseKey;
    end;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Но изменений никаких нет, написал подобное на `c#`

```
    RegistryKey currentUserKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
    RegistryKey helloKey = currentUserKey.OpenSubKey(@"...", true);
    helloKey.SetValue("Health", new byte[] { 07, 00, 00, 00, 0x6F, 0x2B, 15, 00, 40, 0xAB, 0xD3, 01, });
    helloKey.Close();
```

и значение изменилось. Где я в `delphi` ошибся ?

п.с от админа запускаю

Comment: Добавьте обработку ошибок. Сделайте `RaiseLastOSError` если `OpenKey` вернул `False`.

Comment: @zed я поставил остановку на запись `WriteBinaryData` после условия. и компилятор показал, что условие прошло, значит `OpenKey` вернул `True`

Comment: Попробуйте использовать права `KEY_WRITE` или `KEY_ALL_ACCESS`.

Comment: @zed пробовал `Reg.Access := KEY_ALL_ACCESS;` все равно не меняет значение ((

Comment: А путь к ключу правильный? Может он его создаёт, но не там где вы ожидаете?

Comment: @zed правильный, ведь на `c#` то работает, я его скопировал из проекта `delphi`

Comment: Не факт, что то, что было правильно под С#, будет правильно для Delphi и наоборот. Воспользуйтесь поиском по реестру. В любом случае, если бы ключ не создался, произошло бы исключение. Раз исключения нет - ключ создался. Возможно проблемы из-за разных разрядностей винды и приложения (для решения которой есть ключ `KEY_WOW64_64KEY`) и ключ пишется в 32-х битную ветку, а ищите в 64-х битной.

Comment: @zed вы правы, `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` помог, можете оформить, как ответ, спасибо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В 64-х битной Windows для 32-х битных приложений есть т.н. виртуализация, из-за которой эти приложения видят свою, 32-х битную версию реестра ([Alternate Registry View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Для того, чтобы 32-х битное приложение смогло увидеть системную 64-х битную версию реестра, надо использовать флаг [KEY_WOW64_64KEY (0x0100)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> KEY_WOW64_64KEY Indicates that an application on 64-bit Windows should 
>   operate on the 64-bit registry view. This flag is ignored by
>   32-bit Windows.
>
> This flag must be combined using the OR operator with the other flags in this table that either query or access registry values.

То есть, нужно делать так:

```
Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE OR KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
try
...
finally
...
end;
```